# Why can't $\int x(x-3)^8\ dx$ be integrated by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been given the task of integrating the following equation $$\int x(x-3)^8dx$$ but they've all been saying that it must be done via substitution and is impossible to do view integration by parts. I'm wondering why that is.

Video of solution by substition:
https://youtu.be/CXgsorgesS0?t=109

Attempt to solve it by parts: 
$$\int x(x-3)^8dx$$ 
$$ v=x,u'= (x-3)^8 $$
$$ u'=1, u = 1/9(x-3)^9$$
$$\int x(x-3)^8dx = (1/9)x(x-3)^9 -\int 1/9(x-3)^9$$
$$=(1/9)x(x-3)^9 -(1/90)(x-3)^{10}+C$$

Comment: You can do it by integration by parts.

Comment: It can be performed by-parts, albeit substitution is easier. Take $(x-3)^8$ as the function to differentiate. Solve by-parts repeatedly using the same rule.

Comment: This is such a trivial integration -- why bother with any special method? (Just do it).

Comment: I know it's trivial but I still want to know why it can't be done by parts

Comment: _Never_ trust your teacher. The mathematics will show.

Comment: Usually we use integration by parts when one of the functions become a constant after we derive it finite number of times. Another thing when we have a product of two functions it is the natural way to think about integration by parts

Comment: In integration by parts you differentiate one part of the integrand and integrate another part.  When the whole integrand is a polynomial, differentiating one part removes one factor of $x$ but integrating the other part adds one, so you are back where you started in terms of the degree of the polynomial.  If you can integrate $x^n$ but not $(x-3)^n$ or if you can integrate $(x-3)^n$ but not $x(x-3)^n$ this is still an improvement.

Comment: Who are "they" in "they've all been saying"??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it can be done by parts, treating $(x-3)^8$ as the expression to integrate and $x$ as the expression to differentiate:
$$\int x(x-3)^8\,dx=x\cdot\frac19(x-3)^9-\int\frac19(x-3)^9\,dx=\frac19x(x-3)^9-\frac1{90}(x-3)^{10}+K=\frac1{30}(3x+1)(x-3)^9+K$$
To get to the book answer:
$$\frac1{30}(3x+1)(x-3)^9+K=\frac{3x-9+10}{30}(x-3)^9+K=\left(\frac{x-3}{10}+\frac13\right)(x-3)^9+K=\frac{(x-3)^{10}}{10}+\frac{(x-3)^9}3+K$$

Comment: That's different from the answer on the mark scheme,

Comment: http://ibmaths.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/HL-Revision-Cards-61_70.004.jpeg
It's B which is the answer they give

Comment: @ZubinJAIN Well, the two expressions are equivalent. I do expect IB markers to notice the equivalence.

Comment: Realy, I don't see how they are equivalent

Comment: @ZubinJAIN You can manipulate that answer to get my answer. This shows they are equivalent.

Comment: @ZubinJAIN I've added a conversion to the exact book answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks so much. I was feeling so dumb for not getting why my answer was wrong, thanks for showing me that it was in fact correct

Comment: @ZubinJAIN For future reference, in single variable calculus, if you want to compare the results of two indefinite integrals, just subtract one expression from the other. If the answer is a constant, then the two answers are equivalent. In this case, the difference is zero, but it can be a non-zero constant as well.

Comment: I know this is trivial, but did you use substitution to solve $\int(x-3)^9$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri No.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Not explicitly, but surely, implicitly?

Comment: @Deepak Just cutting the uninteresting bits, really; adding a constant to the $x$ only changes there, and does not introduce additional factors.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I know but most people would still consider even a trivial linear substitution done mentally to be a substitution. I guess you could say you directly applied the "standard integral" $\int (ax+b)^n dx = \frac 1{a(n+1)}(ax+b)^{n+1} +c$, but that's usually derived from a linear sub in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the substitution $x \mapsto x \! + \! 3$ moves the $8^\text{th}$ power from the binomial onto the monomial $x$, making the integrand much easier to attack directly:

$$\int x(x-3)^8 \ \text{d}x \ = \ \int (x+3)x^8 \ \text{d}x \ = \ \int x^9 + 3x^8 \ \text{d}x$$

Relative to this, IBP involves more work.  Despite inefficient choices for $u$ and $\text{d}v$ relative to **Parcly Taxel**'s answer (+1), the following demonstrates that IBP is not only possible, but can be carried out *in more than one way*.

> $\textbf{Warning: }$Unnecessarily hard, but posting for pedagogical value.  If one were asked on a test to solve this integral by parts, we advise—in no uncertain terms—to use Parcly Taxel's choices for $u$ and $\text{d}v$.  For illustrative purposes only!

Letting $u = (x-3)^8$ and $\text{d}v = x$, we get:

$$\int x(x-3)^8 \ \text{d}x \ = \ \frac{1}{2}x^2(x-3)^8 - \int4x^2(x-3)^7 \ \text{d}x$$

To solve the newly-created integral, you can proceed similarly with $u = (x-3)^7$ and $\text{d}v = 4x^2$.  Continue as such until the binomial disappears with $\text{d}u = \text{d}x$; at this point the final integral of the form $\displaystyle \int v \ \text{d}u$ should look something like $\displaystyle \int cx^8 \ \text{d}x$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$.  Solve this integral and, lastly, add all of the terms together.

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way for IBP (in the sense of deciding which one to integrate)...

Comment: Each time, the power on the binomial decreases in the newly-created integral until you're left with something like $\displaystyle \int cx^8 \ dx$, and then that can be done directly and one sums it and all the proceeding terms.  I hope I'm not being stupid :/

Comment: Oh yes, I readily acknowledge this @Parcly.  I'm just having fun :P

Comment: You could have done only _one_ IBP, as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $x$ as the function to differentiate and $(x-3)^8$ as the function to integrate, then $$\int{x(x-3)^8}=\frac{x(x-3)^9}{9}-\frac{1}{9}\int{(x-3)^9}$$
$$=\frac{x(x-3)^9}{9}-\frac{(x-3)^{10}}{90}$$

Comment: Plus a constant whoops.

Comment: I got that answer but it's wrong according to the markscheme
http://ibmaths.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/HL-Revision-Cards-61_70.004.jpeg

Comment: Answer B) on the markscheme is the right answer according to them